# Magento add additional field for give product hight and width

Tags: magento, product

i have to add 2 text input field for Magento  product detail page. That will be hight and width for every product. when a customer buy any product, they will give product  hight and width and click the add to cart.

also as per product hight and width product price will change

done any one know how do i do that?

Thank you
M

Answer (score 0):

I think You can do it by making products configurable.Where you will define different attributes for each product.for detail check the [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/)

Comment: Hello Mahmood Rehman, Thank you for your reply but i already know how to setup configurable products. FYI configurable products only work with radio and drop down not text input field. Anyway

Thank you
M

Comment: Here is example i have been looking for http://www.curtainexpress.co.uk/curtains/megaflow/2122

Answer (score 0):

Magento will not do this out of the box but an extension can help you do this. You can either develop your own or check out the following extensions which will meet your needs:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pricing-calculator-7066.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-variation-pricing.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i like http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-variation-pricing.html plugin but its way too expansive for me to buy. if you have this plugin please share with me :)